# Chef: How to gather local network.interface attribute with state key equal to up?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm interested in gathering the key value for any network_interfaces_*_state:up attribute's running on the host with the chef-client being run on. So any network interface with a state 'up' attribute.

I have a template containing a configuration file, in which I need to gather the active network devices, using the above chef attribute. I've tried writing a few things within the default recipe file, such as:

```
template '/etc/foo.conf' do
    ....
    variables ({
        netdev: search(node, 'network_interfaces_*_state:up').each {r |r| puts "#{r['network']['interfaces'].select { |i,j| j['state'] == 'up' }.keys } " }
    })
end
```

So there are two things that are obviously wrong.

1. Running this as knife exec -E "......" returns the interface name for state:up on all nodes. I only want it from the current node that the chef-client is being run on.
2. chef-client is returning an undefined method 'search' for Chef::Resource::Template, tracing back to the 'netdev' variable as posted above.

I'm unfamiliar with Ruby and using Chef at this level, and was really hoping that I could get help with understanding two things. How do I pull a attribute value from a local host, and how the heck can I write this into a recipe/cookbook?

Comment: I still don't get why you want all nodes in your chef server interface for a single attribute... are you looping over it later ? How is this attribute supposed to be used ?

Comment: That's just it, I don't. I don't know how to do a search without using a node index to list all the nodes, and using client as an index doesn't load any results either. This is where my inexperience comes into play. When loading a node attribute, it's typically as easy as node['hostname'], but doesn't appear to be as simple when running that search query.

Comment: Just forget the search part, I'll edit my answer later in the morning, you just need the select part (probably with an exclusion of loopback interface)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I've been working on this for the past couple days, and unfortunately, can't get this to work yet. I've tried similar variations to the post above, including removing the search method, which requires removal of .each as it returns as an undefined method (rightfully so, if it's no longer looping through each node). I just can't figure out the query to pull locally. From my understanding, the second half of the query gets the result I want, but the first half does not get the local node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need is the first 'up' interface, assuming the loopback interface should be avoided, this should do:

```
template '/etc/foo.conf' do
    ....
    variables ({
        netdev: node['network']['interfaces'].select { |i,j| j['state'] == 'up' && i != 'lo' }.keys[0]
    })
end
```

The main idea is to filter the interfaces hash on the interface state and name, keep the keys and take the first one of the resulting array.

---

Previous answer kept for information.

Attributes are [indexed and flattened](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html#nested-fields) so you may search for just `state:up` but may find other attributes named state.

Using the flattened version you could do:

`knife node search 'network_interface_*_state:up' -a network.interfaces`

This is derived from the examples of nested fields in the documentation linked above.

In case you wish to get each interface up for each node you can play with the search and a little of ruby with `knife exec` like this :

```
 knife exec -E "nodes.search('network_interfaces_*_state:up').each { |n| puts \"#{n} #{n['network']['interfaces'].select { |i,j| j['state'] == 'up' }.keys } \" }"
node[xxxxxxx] ["eth1", "eth2", "eth3", "usb0"]
node[yyyyyyy] ["docker0"]
node[zzzzzzz] ["eth1", "eth2", "eth3", "usb0"]
```

The idea is to search for nodes with up interfaces and for each filtering the interfaces whose property (`j` in `select` block as they are a hash within a hash) state is up and then keep only the `keys` of the resulting filtered hash which are the interfaces with state up. (side note my examples above were done with state:down to limit the results)

Comment: I like the flattened version of the query that you suggested. This will be written in a recipe, so I was hoping to define the variable in the attributes, and wanted to do something like:
    default['netdev'] = node.search('network_interfaces_*_state:up')
This won't work of course since the search method is undefined. Will the search method work for me in either the templates/attributes, or recipe directly?

Comment: Yes, just use search, but you'll need to filter the interface list and probably take only the first one, but if it is for the current node there's a more straightforward way than search. You should edit your question to give more details on why you want this value and for which node

Comment: At this point you kind of might as well just use `*:*` as the search unless you expect to have a lot of Chef nodes with no network interfaces :)

Comment: @Tensibai I've sat down tonight to describe in better detail the current issue I face. Your knife exec -E statement was very helpful, along with knowing that indexes can be flattened. I was able to pull out just the interface device names, but for the entire inventory, not the local host. My big issues are how to I run it for the local host where the chef-client runs, and where does it fit in the cookbook (recipe vs attributes vs template)?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I see what you've done now in your updated query, thanks for breaking it down. Best answer, as it resolved my issues!